# Weird CSS issue with margin's

Tags: css

I'm having a weird issue with this section I am styling..  Effectively, I have a container element that is 906px wide, and then four spans inside that should all line up side by side and be spaced evenly ..  What is happening is the last element has flowed to a new line.  I've tried variations of last-child and last-of-type to fix this, but Nothing I am doing is working.  I even resorted to hard coding a "last" class and the right margin is still applying to this block of code.  Any ideas?  See the pic below for what is happening.

HTML

```
<div id="internship-carousel" class="group">
    <div id="internship-carousel-container">
        <span class="internship-section">
            <h4>Amnesty International</h4>
            <img src="img/intern_logo/amnesty.png" class="intern_logo" alt="Amnesty International">
        </span>
        <span class="internship-section">
            <h4>State of Georgia</h4>
            <img src="img/intern_logo/georgia.png" class="intern_logo" alt="Amnesty International">
        </span> 
        <span class="internship-section">
            <h4>Department of State</h4>
            <img src="img/intern_logo/statedepartment.png" class="intern_logo" alt="Amnesty International">
        </span> 
        <span class="internship-section internship-section-last">
            <h4>CARE</h4>
            <img src="img/intern_logo/care.png" class="intern_logo" alt="Amnesty International">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#internship-carousel{margin-top:50px;}
.internship-section{
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0px;
    width: 190px;
    height:225px;
    margin-right:44px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.internship-section h4{
    padding-top:15px;}
}
span.internship-section-last
{
    margin:0;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo on your code:

```
.internship-section h4{
    padding-top:15px;}
}
```

Remove the `}` after the `padding-top` declaration and you should be golden. ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ONIJEFo/1))

The demo makes use of the `:last-child` selector by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css and remove the last class

```
.internship-section:nth-child(4){
    margin-right:0px
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also doesn't fix it.